# How to reduce the font size in script mode in Katalon?

Tags: testing, katalon-studio

I would like to know if there is any way to reduce the font size in script mode because with bigger text only few lines are visible when working on laptops. Needs lot of scrolling which is not the best experience.

Answer (score 1):

Window -> Katalon Studio Preferences -> General - > Appearance - > Colors and Fonts .... And now edit Text Font to prefered font size